# simply boolean expression into 4 literals

Tags: calculus

$( (A + B) + A'B' ) ( C'D' + CD) + A'C'  $

Simply to 4 literals

We know that

- $A'B' = A' + B' $
- $C'D' = C + D  $
- $A + A' = 1  $

So,

$( ( A + B)+ A' + B') (C'D' + CD) + A'C'     $

$(1)\;\;(C'D' + CD) + A'C'   $

- $(C' + D ' + CD) + A'C'  $
- $C' + A'C' + D' + CD  $
- $C'(1 + A') + D' + CD  $
- $C'(1) + D' + CD   $
- $C' + D' + CD.  $

Is the above equal to 4 literals?

Comment: $A'B'$ is equivalent to $(A \lor B)'$. $A' \lor B'$ is equivalent to $(AB)'$.